# JavaScript - Do something with a message received through websocket.onmessage

Tags: javascript, api, websocket

In short, I'm trying to manipulate my webpage by sending messages to it via a websocket from my backend. When my page loads up, the websocket connection is established. When my page closes or refreshes, my page cuts the connection. The idea is that my backend (aws lambda fn) will send a message through the websocket to my HTML page, and then I will do something with the message. Here is a snippet that explains this simple, but troublesome code:

```
window.onload = function() {
    socket = setupWebSocket();
    
};

window.addEventListener('beforeunload', function(event) {
    socket.close()
})

function setupWebSocket() {
    socket = new WebSocket("wss://*****.amazonaws.com/dev");

    socket.onmessage = function(event) {
        console.log(event) // This logs out fine

        // I want to now run this function with the event data
        // However, it won't let me. It says event is undefined
        showTheList(event.data.urls);
    }
     
    return socket;
}


function showTheList(url_list) {
    // Do something with the list of urls
}
```

console.log(event) produces the following log

```
MessageEvent {isTrusted: true, data: "{"action": "show_images", "urls": ["https://*****"]}", origin: "wss://******.amazonaws.com", lastEventId: "", source: null, …}
bubbles: false
cancelBubble: false
cancelable: false
composed: false
currentTarget: WebSocket {url: "wss://********.amazonaws.com/dev", readyState: 1, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: null, onerror: null, …}
data: "{"action": "show_images", "urls": ["https://*****/show?id=1020010095886C00", "https://*****/show?id=102001008CB55900", "https://*****/show?id=102001008E367000", "https://*****/show?id=103001009CAF3400", "https://*****/show?id=10400100534ADC00", "https://*****/show?id=102001008C81F600"]}"
defaultPrevented: false
eventPhase: 0
isTrusted: true
lastEventId: ""
origin: "wss://*****.amazonaws.com"
path: []
ports: []
returnValue: true
source: null
srcElement: WebSocket {url: "wss://*****.amazonaws.com/", readyState: 1, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: null, onerror: null, …}
target: WebSocket {url: "wss://*****.amazonaws.com/", readyState: 1, bufferedAmount: 0, onopen: null, onerror: null, …}
timeStamp: 9330.839999951422
type: "message"
userActivation: null
__proto__: MessageEvent
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your data is in string format.

Try replacing:

```
showTheList(event.data.urls);
```

With:

```
showTheList(JSON.parse(event.data).urls);
```